# Checking and sending email on interval if certain conditions are met

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, express

I have an express js program in which a function runs in a 10 seconds interval and gets a temperature value.

There is already a temperature threshold, upper threshold and lower threshold value defined by default.

```
temperature_threshold = 30
upper_threshold = temperature_threshold + 2
lower_threshold = temperature_threshold - 2
```

Now on each interval if the current temperature value crosses the temperature threshold value, then send an email of the temperature crossed threshold.

```
if current_temperature >= temperature_threshold
{
    send email;
}
```

After sending the email once if the temperature value lies in the range between lower_threshold and upper_threshold then do not send the email.

But if the temperature, then decreases below the lower_threshold level and then again increases to cross the temperature_threshold value then again send the email.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag variable to record whether an email has already been sent for a temperature breach.

Once the temperature drops below `lower_threshold`, reset the flag.

```js
const temperature_threshold = 30;
const upper_threshold = temperature_threshold + 2;
const lower_threshold = temperature_threshold - 2;

// whether an email has already been sent
let sent = false;

// the function runs every 10 seconds
function check(current_temperature) {
    if (current_temperature <= lower_threshold) {
        sent = false;
    } else if (current_temperature >= temperature_threshold && !sent) {
        /* send email */
        sent = true;
    }
}
```